# DynamoDB - Mutable, One to Many Lookup Table Scenario

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-streams

Assume I had thousands of products and each product had a 1-many relationship to labels (for simplicity sake, let’s call them tags i.e. One Product has many Tags).  Assume the tags are semi-volatile meaning the labels for the tags could get updated a few times a year but not often.  Is the best practice to relate the tags to the product via the sort key and then if the tag label changes for whatever reason, I catch the update to the tag via DynamoDB Streams, trigger a lambda or something similar and run the thousands of DynamoDB updates to the Products that have an access pattern to the Tag or do you think it makes more sense to only store the Tag IDs in the Product (ie traditional SQL like lookup table) and use BatchGetItems to fetch the Tags when I fetch the Product which could save thousands of updates but does require multiple GETs on a given product.

Comment: UPDATE:  FWIW to anyone else out there, this is from the Dynamo Master himself, Alex Debrie (DynamoDB Book):

"My guess is that it's better to do the mass update whenever a tag changes, but it's definitely not a lot of fun" :)